# C# Textbox Failing to Update

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to use FolderBrowserDialog to allow a selected folder to be stored in a string, I then want that string to populate a text box on the application interface.  I can select the file box all well and good and the directory paths are being stored correctly, however they are not auto populating the text box.  If I try to type something into the textbox it will show the string that I want there. Here's the code for the button I'm using to get the directory:

```
 private void openJPEGButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog jpegDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        string selectedFolder = @"C:\";
        jpegDialog.SelectedPath = selectedFolder;

        if (jpegDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            originDirectory = jpegDialog.SelectedPath;
            textBox1.Update(); 

        }
```

And here's the code for the textbox,

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = originDirectory;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the `SelectedPath` to textbox's text.

```
if (jpegDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    originDirectory = jpegDialog.SelectedPath;
    textBox1.Text = jpegDialog.SelectedPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i get you well, you want to extract the path and show it in a `textbox`. You can use

```
private void openJPEGButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog jpegDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    string selectedFolder = @"C:\";
    jpegDialog.SelectedPath = selectedFolder;

    if (jpegDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         textbox1.Text = jpegDialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

You could also use this

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = jpegDialog.SelectedPath;
}
```

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer, though `textBox1.Text = jpegDialog.SelectedPath;` is incorrect as `jpegDialog` is a local variable limited to the `openJPEGButton_Click` method

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to assign `Text` property to this dialog value..

```
textbox1.Text = jpegDialog.SelectedPath;
```